# Not able to use setState() outside of scaffold in flutter

Tags: android, flutter

I have created one method outside the scaffold in the build method but not able to setState() from there.
I have written code like this :

```
    @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    //Method that returns alert dialog
    method(){
       setState(() {
          selectedType = newValue;
          enableBrand = true;
       });
    }
    
    //Main scaffold from where i'm calling the alert dialog method
    return scaffold()
    
    }
```

But this doesn't work, the state is not getting updated, so can anyone suggest what is the issue here?

I want to show an AlertDialog on click of a button so i have created a method for that in the build method and trying to setState() from there but it is not working.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you maybe share all the code in your build method? Your code doesn't make any sense right now

Comment: There is 600 lines of code that's why i have put just these lines

Comment: I have added more explanation in the post itself, please check @Er1

Comment: if you want to update your dialog box, u can warp your  dialog box with stateful builder

Comment: can you please show how? @Mrvd

Comment: add your dialog box UI code in stateful bulder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  void _showDialog() {
showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (context) {
    return StatefulBuilder( // StatefulBuilder
      builder: (context, setState) {
        return AlertDialog(
          actions: <Widget>[
          
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  },
);
```

}

Answer (score 1):

First of all, is your class extending `StatefulWidget`?

In the onPressed of your button you could do something like this example.
An AlertDialog can give back a value when popped. I just took the example Alertdialog for now and returned a String.

Then you can set your state with the new value.

```dart
onPressed: () async {
                var newValue = await showDialog(
                    context: context,
                    builder: (c) => AlertDialog(
                          title: Text('AlertDialog Title'),
                          content: SingleChildScrollView(
                            child: ListBody(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Text('This is a demo alert dialog.'),
                                Text(
                                    'Would you like to approve of this message?'),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          actions: <Widget>[
                            FlatButton(
                              child: Text('Approve'),
                              onPressed: () {
                                Navigator.of(context).pop("YOUR_NEW_VALUE");
                              },
                            ),
                          ],
                        ));

                  //newValue now has the value "YOUR_NEW_VALUE"

                  setState((){
                    selectedType = newValue;
                    enableBrand = true;
                  });
              }
```